# How to enable element highlighting for handlebars in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: handlebars.js, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-plugin

I have selected the Handlebars option in the footer in Sublime Text 3, but when I click on an element, it isn't highlighted to show the beginning and end.

For example, this is what it looks like when I have my cursor in the first `<div>`.

[image: handlebars example]

This is ideally how it should look like (Note the underlined divs):
[image: regular HTML example]

How can I get my handlebar code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, just installed this package: https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter